# Cant ping from one VM workstation to another VM workstation connected through switch hub

Tags: virtual-machine, ping, host, unreachable-statement

I'm trying to set up 2 VMware workstations so that they will be able to communicate between each other. Despite connecting both of them to a hub through lan cable, they still failed to communicate to each other. The result from pinging between both machines shows " Reply from IP address, followed by Destination host unreachable".

Both of their adapter settings are NAT.

[image: IP address of both of my VMware workstations]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. When I did the following steps, my problem was solved. I thought you might have helped.

1) installed vmnet bridge protocol ---> vmnet0 --> properties --->check vmnet bridge protocol

2)updated & reinstalled wireless adapter driver

3)reinstalled vmware & its n/w components